# Multiple lists put side-by-side and with a styled title header

Tags: html, css, validation

I want to have about 7 lists (UL) side-by-side and each list has a separate styled header title. I am trying to get the lists to sort nicely underneath the header title and the bullets also (was thinking using text-indent, but that doesnt work in IE8 apparently!??). I came up with below code (I am a newbie), but again HTML validator is throwing error messages at me. I know I cannot put my styled header title under the UL but thats the only way to get it nicely sorted in one clean straight column. What I am doing wrong?

```
<ul style="width:14%; float:left;">
<span style="font-size: 13px;"><p class="notice">title 1</p></span>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">aaaaa</span></a></li>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">bbbbb</span></a></li>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">ddddd</span></a></li>
</ul>

<ul style="width:14%; float:left;">
<span style="font-size: 13px;"><p class="notice">title2</p></span>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">eeeeee</span></a></li>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">ffffff</span></a></li>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">hhhhhhh</span></a></li>
</ul>

<ul style="width:14%; float:left;">
<span style="font-size: 13px;"><p class="notice">title3</p></span>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">iiiiii</span></a></li>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">kkkkkk</span></a></li>
<li><a class="underline2" href="etc etc"><span 
style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px; color: #616161;">llllllll</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, you have invalid HTML: a `ul` can contain *only* `li` elements as direct children. All other contain must be contained within an `li` element. Further, move your CSS into a stylesheet (since the styles appear to be shared), and indent your code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your html is invalid, and you're using inline styles.

I've included a wrapping div around the lists and headers with a class.

A working example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pf8eR/

Html

```
<div class="column">
    <h2>First Column</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <h2>Second Column</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <h2>Third Column</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css

```
ul, li{
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 15px;    
}

.column{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the validator error messages is that a `ul` element can have only `li` elements as children, and a `span` element must not contain a `p` element. (Any decent tutorial on HTML describes such things.)

On the other hand, your list titles are logically headings rather than paragraphs. It depends on the context what the heading level is, but assuming this construct appears at the top level of hierarchy, `h2` is right. Something like the following (ignoring here the inner structure of the `li` elements, which is not relevant here):

```
<div class=list>
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<ul>
<li>Item one
<li>Item two
<li>Item three
</ul>
</div>
```

The extra `div` element lets you style a list and its heading as a unit. You seem to want something like the result achievable with a style sheet like this:

```
.list { width: 14%; float: left; }
.list h2 { font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal }
.list li { font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14px }
.list ul, .list ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.list ul, .list h2 { margin-left: 1.3em; }
```

Put that in an external style sheet that you link to, or in a `style` element. Copying the same settings over and over again for different elements makes the code hard to read and hard to maintain.

The font sizes above are as per your code. It would be much better not to set font size for list items at all and set the font size of the headings to something suitably larger than copy text size, e.g. `font-size: 115%`.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. dmc already mentioned the same. i will take over your advise on the css styling... dont know why but i always used inline styling as it was validated... thanks again! very clear and helpful explanation.

Comment: hi, if i may ask... how do i push the first list (and consequently the other 5 lists automatically) all to the right a bit, lets stay 40px...??? (all lists together are not centered (the texts are ok, they dont need to be centered, i mean just the list columns). thanks.

Comment: @Simon, that’s really a new question, but you can simply use `style="margin-left: 40xp"` in the first `ul` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may try aplying this css to the ul tag.

```
ul{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```